# Concatenate Returns in Sharepoint Wrokflow into single field update

Tags: sharepoint, list, workflow

I have two lists in *sharepoint*:

- One is a list (#1) with two Columns: *Name* and *Birthday*.
- The other list (#2) has many columns, but organizes by birthday. 
  **For instance:** *birthday*, *zodiac sign*, *names of people with that birthday*.

I am trying to create a workflow such that whenever someone enters a new birthday into **list #2**, the names column is automatically populated with a concatenated string of names of people with that birthday from **list #1**.

*How can I achieve this?*

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or Sharepoint Designer?

Comment: Only have Sharepoint Designer

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your trying to do (forgetting HOW you're trying to do it). I think I understand what your trying to do (show for anyone's birthday who else has that birthday) and if so there is an easier way that using workflow.

Comment: Sure, to your point, I do not exactly care how it is done. I am trying to reference a list for which multiple entries could meet some criteria (have the same birthday) and then display all of those entries in one string (concatenate). Imagine Bob, Jim, and John all have a birthday of Jan 1st and are in separate rows in list #1. In list #2, when Jan 1st is entered as a birthday, I want Bob, Jim, and John to all appear in that Jan 1st row, under the column "people with this birthday". Hope this helps!